# Django 1.6 AbstractUser does not allow fields to be saved with HTML Form

Tags: python, django

I extended the User object in Django 1.6 and added some extra fields. I have a form that allows the user to add their username and irc name to their User Object. But when I save using the form, the information is not being committed to the database(not being saved). I don't have any errors and the Post for the form is 200 ok.

```
class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2 control-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-4'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset('Account Modify',
                'irc_name',
                'forum_username',
                ),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
                )
            )


class Employee(AbstractUser):
    irc_name = models.CharField(max_length="25")
    forum_username = models.CharField(max_length="25")


class AccountModify(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = AccountForm
    template_name = 'bot_data/account_modify.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

Comment: In your `AccountModify` view are you getting an instance of the `Employee` class or the model?

Comment: `class Employee(AbstractUser)` is in models.py, so hopefully it is grabbing the model. In the python shell I am able to do `Employee.objects.all()` successfully to show the database object is there(but fields are not populated after the form save).